# 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, svn, command-line

example for download project

---

cd xampp\htdocs>svn co http://svn.doctrine-project.org/trunk doctrine

then error

---

'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 39):

In case if someone is looking to install Command line client tools on top of already installed `Tortoise`, you can do this.

1. Download the latest from website (https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) and open the exe.
2. When you reach this screen (see below), untick all, but `command line client tools'.
3. Press "Next" and continue the installation.

This will only install `command line client tools` on top of your existing Tortoise.

Hope this will help someone. Cheers!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Subversion is not installed by default on Windows. You have to install it to be able to use 'svn' command lines. Packages can be found here:  http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Answer (score 1):

You can download TortoiseSVN and while installing choose CLI package. Once after installation add the folder location to Environment Variables->System variables